# Why is error message stating TEMPDB has insufficient disk space in filegroup 'DEFAULT' when my TEMPDB filegroup is named 'PRIMARY'

Tags: sql-server, tempdb

I have a remote user getting this error message when running a query.

> Could not allocate a new page for database 'TEMPDB' because of
> insufficient disk space in filegroup 'DEFAULT'. Create the necessary
> space by dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to
> the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the
> filegroup.

TEMPDB currently has nearly 100% space available. The filegroup for my TEMPDB is named 'PRIMARY', but the error message is referencing a filegroup named 'DEFAULT'. Before I begin looking at the query or consider expanding TEMPDB I want to confirm that the correct filegroup is being used. What would be the reason for the difference in filegroup names?

[image]

Comment: Not sure why some messages specify `DEFAULT` instead of `PRIMARY` but every database has a default filegroup (`SELECT name, is_default FROM sys.filegroups; `) which is the primary filegroup (one with mdf file) unless another filegroup was designated as the default. Your tempdb looks like it filled at some point but the ephemeral space was since released.

Comment: @DanGuzman I was able to obtain the query and ran it from my machine. Freespace did not drop below 80% and it completed without error. The inconsistency in the Filegroup name makes me think something else is going on. Could SQL be using disk space on his machine (or within Citrix) for tempdb instead of the actual tempdb drive? Maybe that is why he is running our of disk space and why the filegroup name is different.

Comment: SQL Server uses only the tempdb data/log files for tempdb space. The filegroup name is just a red herring. Consider there may be other activity than the single query on the server and 5 concurrent executions of the query will fill tempdb unless there is space to autogrow.